# Update Multiple Rows - Kendo JQuery Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using the cellClose event to update cell values, it works within the values in the selected row.  I have a last row called Total which is the sum of the Values of the Column D

----------Column_A Column_B Column_C Column_D

----------Product1---ValueB1---ValueC1-------ValueD1

----------Product2---ValueB2---ValueC2-------ValueD2

----------Total------------------------------------------ValueT

Column D= Column_C * Column_B and ValueT = ValueD1 + ValueD2

When i update ValueC1 or ValueB1 , ValueD1 gets updated and re-rendered with the new value . The problem is that the ValueT gets udpated but it doesnt re-render .

The code i have is this one :

```
cellClose:function(e){
var dataItem=e.sender.dataItem($(e.container).parent())// getting the current edited row
var aux= e.sender.dataSource.data(); //getting all rows
var dataTotal= aux[aux.length-1]; //geting total row

valueB=dataItem["Column_B"];
valueC=dataItem["Column_C"];
dataItem.set("Column_D",valueB*ValueC);

  var sum=0;
   for (let i=0;i<aux.length-1;i++)//getting sum of values of Column_D
   {
           sum=sum+aux[i].Column_D;
   } 
  dataTotal.set("Column_D",sum) // setting sum


}
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in aggregates? https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates

Comment: No , i'm not ussing built in aggregates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use built-in aggregates as on https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates , they're exactly for that case. Programming is all about choosing the right tool for the job.
2. Your loop should only iterate to `aux.length-2`, otherwise you're adding the old sum to the new one. That's a mistake you could have avoided by using built-in aggregates.
3. The call `var aux= e.sender.dataSource.data()` returns you [an array](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/data) with the grid's data, but the grid is not bound to that array. It's bound to the dataSource. You can bind it to your modified array by doing `e.sender.dataSource.data()`, or, instead of doing all this work, use the built-in aggregates.

Comment: Thank you , i ussed aggregates and it worked + this https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/update-aggregates-on-change